# How can we retrieve automatically every new playlist created by a user

Tags: deezer

I'm discovering the Deezer API and wondering how I could retrieve autoamtically the new playlists I create with my user.

Or maybe I can create a folder, and store my playlists on that folder ?
The problem is : I don't know how to create a folder and I did not notice any button in the Deezer interface to do it.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

The folder feature is deprecated (it has already been removed from the website, and will also be removed from the APIs).

I am not really sure what you're trying to do. If you wan't to retrieve all playlist created by a specific user account, you can use the following API request :

```
http://api.deezer.com/user/1248300/playlists
```

The response will contain a JSON of all playlist that the user created or has in his favorites. You can then for each playlist check the creator field which contains the information about the user who created the playlist.

If you want to know which playlist was created with your application, that's more tricky as the API doesn't have any option to know that. You could name your playlist in a specific pattern, or keep track of the playlists in your own database.